# python ctypes malloc returns an Int instead of void*

Tags: python, ctypes

I have to interface with some c code where I have to pass in a buffer with some data. I want to allocate this buffer in python and set the values, however `malloc` returns an `Int` object instead of a correct `ctypes.c_void_p`. I assume I am doing something wrong... I would appreciate and pointers! Below is a minimal example which illustrates the issue:

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('c'))
libc.malloc.argtypes = [ctypes.c_size_t]
libc.malloc.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

mem = libc.malloc(ctypes.c_size_t(300))
t = type(mem) # <type 'int'>
```

Comment: From the documentation for `c_void_p`: "Represents the C void * type. The value is represented as integer."  If you want memory you can write to, you have to cast the value to something of the correct size: `(ctypes.c_char * 300).from_address(mem)` perhaps.

Comment: Note `ctypes.c_size_t(300)` is unnecessary.  You've told `ctypes` via `libc.malloc.argtypes` that the first parameter is a `c_size_t`.  You can just say `libc.malloc(300)`.  For input parameters `ctypes` will convert for you.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes that works. This forces me to cast it back to a pointer once I want to pass it to the C function, If you post this as an answer I will accept it!

Comment: Shorter: `libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)`.